# My Dropdown Menu isnt working

Tags: html, css

My dropdown menu isn't working, however it was up until yesterday and I cant figure out what's wrong and I have double checked the code so

```css
#apDiv2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: none;
  z-index: 6;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 6
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="apDiv2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="homeA2.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">WORLD WAR 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="HOWITBEGANA2.html">HOW IT BEGAN AND ENDED</a>
        <a href="SOILDERSLIFEA2.html">A SOLIDERS LIFE</a>
        <a href="WOMENSJOBA2.html">A WOMENS JOB</a>
      </div>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">NOTABLE FIGURES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="NotableFigures1A2.html">NOTABLE FIGURES PART 1</a>
          <a href="NotableFigures2A2.html">NOTABLE FIGURES PART 2</a></div>
        <li><a href="CommentsA2.html">COMMENTS AND QUETIONS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#apDiv2`:

```css
#apDiv2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: none;
  z-index: 6;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 6
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="apDiv2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="homeA2.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">WORLD WAR 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="HOWITBEGANA2.html">HOW IT BEGAN AND ENDED</a>
        <a href="SOILDERSLIFEA2.html">A SOLIDERS LIFE</a>
        <a href="WOMENSJOBA2.html">A WOMENS JOB</a>
      </div>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">NOTABLE FIGURES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="NotableFigures1A2.html">NOTABLE FIGURES PART 1</a>
          <a href="NotableFigures2A2.html">NOTABLE FIGURES PART 2</a></div>
        <li><a href="CommentsA2.html">COMMENTS AND QUETIONS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're using the CSS rule `overflow: hidden` on both your `#apDiv2` and `ul` elements. Remove the rule from them and you should see your dropdown menus.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#apDiv2`, it is forcing the browser to block the dropdown content.

You should be using

```
#apDiv2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: none;
  z-index: 6;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` causes all things that are displayed outside the original element's rectangle to get cropped and hidden. When you remove this line, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow: hidden from #apDiv2

```
#apDiv2 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    z-index: 6;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333333;
    z-index: 6
}
```

here is a jsfiddle that works https://jsfiddle.net/1bnpxdzb/1/